# html showing in php mail

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to send a php mail but it seems that I have a error in my foreach because the mail shows html..
This is my code:

```
 <form method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Contact Form</legend>
          <label for="fullname">Votre Nom :
            <input id="fullname" name="fullname" type="text" value="nelson" />
          </label>
          <label for="emailaddress" class="margin">Votre e-mail:
            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" />
          </label>
          <label for="message">Message:<br />
            <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="40" rows="8"></textarea>
          </label>
          <p>
             <input id="submit-button" class="button gray stripe" type="submit" name="submit" value="Envoyer le message" />
          &nbsp;</p>
        </fieldset>
      </form>

      <?php
      foreach ($_POST as $value) {
    $value = strip_tags($value);
    $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
}

      $name = $_POST["fullname"];
      $email = "email:" .$_POST["email"];
      $message = "Nom: <br/>" .$name. "email:<br/> " .$email. "message: " .$_POST["message"];
      $to="email@hotmail.com";
      $suject="site internet";
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      mail($to, $suject, $message);
      echo"mail had been sent";
      }
      ?>
```

Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Content-type header in your email message:

```
$name = $_POST["fullname"];
$email = "email:" .$_POST["email"];
$message = "Nom: <br/>" .$name. "email:<br/> " .$email. "message: " .$_POST["message"];
$to="email@hotmail.com";
$suject="site internet";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
mail($to, $suject, $message, $headers);
echo"mail had been sent";
```

Your message body also needs to be contained in `<html>` tags.

Comment: Any time. If this works for you please consider marking this as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your foreach is kind of useless, just do that. More fast than a loops

```
$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST["fullname"]));
$email = "email:" .strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]));
$message = "Nom: <br/>" .$name. "email:<br/> " .$email. "message: " .strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST["message";));
```

Answer (score 0):

To send email containing HTML you must set the header so that the email client knows that the email contains HTML. You also have to make the body of your email an HTML document.

```
$header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
mail($to, $suject, $message, $header);
```

And then in the message itself:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Content here
    </body>
</html>
```